# PHP Session won't register certain values

Tags: php, session

Unless I am missing something basic, this is very odd.

When I fetch data from my db to set it in a session, it doesn't work, however if I set the value manually, it gets set.

**This doesn't work.**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE price='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$price = $row['price'];

$_SESSION['order_details'] = array("price"=>$price);
```

**This works.**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE price='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$price = $row['price'];

$price = '9.99';  

$_SESSION['order_details'] = array("price"=>$price);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have debugged `$row["price"]` and confirmed that it actually contains something?

Comment: Yes, $row["price"] contains something.

Comment: Sounds like you're not getting your expected value from the DB.

Comment: My first thought would be that $row["price"] is null.  The where clause looks a little odd price = $id .....

Comment: I echo $row["price"] right before setting the session and it returns just fine. I have just tried in Firefox and it works, but it doesn't work in Chrome. What gives?

Comment: PHP code is executed on the server, so it wouldn't matter what the browser is; if you're seeing different results from different browsers, then perhaps one browser is caching a page and you're not seeing the current response.

Comment: Yep, it's gotta be a caching problem. Clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will report back.

Comment: Clearing cache didn't change a thing, however I have discovered that my friendly urls are causing trouble with chrome, but not the other browsers.

Comment: Minor stylistic tip: `$_SESSION['older_details']['price'] = $price` works exactly the same as using `array()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friendly URLs were messing up in Chrome. Nothing was wrong with my sessions.

Comment: So this question is no longer relevant, right? If so, please close or delete your question or leave a message and I’ll do it.

Answer (score 0):

in first example (which doesn't work) $price is an array. And you trying adding this array to another array with `array("price"=>$price);`

but second example , as you can see, $price isn't an array (`$price = '9.99';`), so you can add this to another array.